# using shadow dom in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, shadow-dom

The below code works in chrome but not in Internet Explorer. Is there any way to use it in Internet Explorer?

```
    <html>
      <head></head>
     <body>
  <div>
    <h4>My Content Heading</h4>
    <p>My content text</p>
  </div>

  <script>
   var myContent = document.querySelector('div');  
   var shadowroot = myContent.createShadowRoot(); 
   shadowroot.innerHTML =
   '<h2>Inserted Heading</h2> <content select="p"></content>';
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: not supported in IE11

Answer (score 3):

Internet explorer (and new Edge browser) doesn't support shadow DOM natively.
You can use [polyfill](https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs) to achieve desired behaviour.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you please give some reference or sample code to use polyfill.

Comment: The polyfills purpose - is providing API like native, so you should just include script into your page, write some code with shadow DOM usage. And it should work.